# Add text at the end of valueForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got some code pulling data from a plist:

```
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[myArray1 objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"myImage"]];
```

I want to be able to add text to the end of the value that is being pulled from the plist. So instead of the app seeing `filename` it would see `filename_addonText.png`. How can I do this?

Currently, I've got three plist entries with the same filename, but different addon texts (see example below). So I want to add these in the code so that I've only got one entry. I hope I explained my intent well enough...

`string1 > myImage_addon1.png`

`string2 > myImage_addon2.png`

`string3 > myImage_addon3.png`

would instead be:

`string1> myImage`

and the code would add the `addon1.png`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *name = [[myArray1 objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"myImage"];
name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", name, @"_addon1.png"];
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
```

From what I understand this is what you wanted? Append the string right?

My Objc was rusty, fixed up syntax

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to append a string to another string:

```
NSString *baseImageName = myArray1[indexValue][@"myImage"];
NSString *imageName = [baseImageName stringByAppendingString: @"_addon1.png"];
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Or in Swift:

```
let baseImageName = myArray1[indexValue][@"myImage"]!
let imageName = baseImageName + "_addon1.png"
myImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```